# How do I run a makefile such that it doesn't exit on error and continues the compilation of remaining files?

Tags: linux, gcc, build, makefile

I have a makefile that I run and I do not want it to exit if there is an error during the compilation of a particular file. I want it to continue compiling other files. Is this possible? If yes how?

Comment: How is it supposed to compile those other files when one of its dependencies is broken?

Comment: Assume that the remaining files to be built do not have dependencies on the previously built files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-k option I would assume, does that not do what you would want?